# Verification of a different approach for the longest path in an undirected tree

Tags: algorithm, path, tree

I was trying this problem - 
Finding the longest path in an unweighted, undirected tree.

## Approach 1

```
Perform BFS from any node(say X) to the farthest possible node(say Y).
*   Then, perform BFS again from Y to its farthest node(say Z).
*   Y-Z is the required length.
*   For keeping track of length we can either keep a flag in the queue
*   or keep a predecessor array which can be updated for every node that we insert
*   in the queue.
```

Brief, intuitive explanation -
The node X that we start with, would always try to reach the node which is a part of THE longest path(say YZ). Thus, crossing the longest path(say at node N). And from there onwards, it would have two options - either go on one(NZ) side of the longest path or the other(NY).It would take the longer of NY and YZ. So,we would end up reaching one end of the longest path(node Y). Now, had X taken a path other than the one( max(NY,NZ) ) overlapping with THE longest path(YZ),this would, summarily, imply that there is a longer path than THE longest path(YZ).

**Proof by contradiction -**

**case 1-** 
Let us assume if there is some path XT which doesn't overlap with YZ and is longer than XN+max(NY,NZ).
Assume S be the Lowest Common Ancestor of N and T. Now, Let Length(UV) be a function which tells the length of path between 2 nodes u and v.

```
We know, Length(XT) = Length(XS) + Length(ST)                 ..... 1
         Length(XY) = Length(XS) + Length(SN) + Length(NY)    ..... 2     
         Length(XZ) = Length(XS) + Length(SN) + Length(NZ)    ..... 3
```

Without loss of generality, let us assume, `Length(NY)>Length(NZ) ... 4`
Now, we claim that `Length(XT) > Length(XY).`
Thus, using 1,2 and 4,
 we get, `Length(ST) > Length(SN) + Length(NY).`
 But, in that case, in the longest path YZ, if we replace NY by NT i.e. NS+ST, we would get a  path longer than YZ. Then YZ would not remain the longest path .Thus, a contradiction !

Hence proved that `XN + max(NY,NZ)` is the longest path starting from X and would take us to Y which is proved to be one end of the absolute longest path.

Similarly, we can prove for the **case 2** - when XT has a partial overlap with YZ. It is left as an exercise for the reader.

### **Approach 2** (Yet to be verified as correct)

**My solution along with the correction suggested by akul**(http://codeforces.com/blog/entry/2845#comment-200512)

(I might have read this or something similar long time back but am not able to correlate/recall) -

```
*   START -
*   Store all the nodes with their degrees.
*   1. Make a list of nodes of the Tree storing the "Degree" of each node along with the neighbors of the node. 
*
*   2.Initialize length=0;
*
*   3. While there are edges present in the tree, perform the following
*      a. remove the edges connecting all the nodes having degree 1. 
*
*      b.   if(number of edges removed >=2 ) length+=2;
*           else length+=1
*
*      c. update degree of node and its neighbors and the edge information
*
*   return length
*   END.
```

So, here, what I am essentially doing is tapering down the longest path, 
starting from all the boundary(degree 1) nodes as the longest path would 
be the one connecting two 1 degree nodes(the farthest ones).

**My Question - is this approach(approach 2) valid?**

Comment: Yes, it's valid.  OTOH your reasoning for approach #1 is shaky: "The node X that we start with, would always try to reach the node which is a part of THE longest path(say YZ)" -- that property is what you *need to prove* to show that this approach is correct (and it is).

Comment: @j_random_hacker - thanks for confirmation. I have updated the proof as you said. Actually, at my first attempt I was struggling to draw a tree, so I skipped the proof. Now, I got an alternative ! Please check and confirm the validity of Case 1 of the proof. Case 2 has been skipped.

Comment: Is there any name for Approach 2? Is there any similar algorithm that uses this approach(not considering Minimum Spanning Tree algorithms).

Comment: "Let us assume if there is some path XT which doesn't overlap with YZ and is longer than XN+max(NY,NZ)" -- a problem here is that you are already assuming that N exists -- but you haven't proved this yet, only assumed it, so the contradiction later only tells you that (at least) one of these 2 assumptions is incorrect.  The proof should begin, "Suppose there is a path UV that is longer than YZ" -- that is, it should *not* assume that the longest path involves any of the vertices X, Y or Z that you have calculated.  You can then break this down into cases and show a contradiction for each.

Comment: I'm not aware of a name for the second approach, I'm afraid.  To prove its correctness, you can prove (easily, via contradiction) that a longest path in a tree must begin and end at distinct leaves, then show that any leaf that exists after "trimming" leaves must not have been a leaf in the original tree, so any max-length path in the trimmed tree can be extended at each end in the original tree.

Comment: I am sorry, din't actually get your point. I think there are only two possibilities - 1. The farthest point from X being Y(one of the corner node of the longest path) and 2. It not being Y. The remaining case - when XY and YZ don't overlap but still BFS on X gives us Y - is a trivial case in which S coincides with X and Y coincides with T. We would still have an alteranative - ZX+XY > ZY. Thus a contradiction. Is this what you are referrring to?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I agree with @j_random_hacker that the approach is valid, and can be proven by contradiction:

To prove that the two end nodes must have degree 1

- assume that there is an end node A with degree N, where N>1
- note that the path must contain one of the N edges entering A
- note that exiting A through one of the other edges would extend the path
- hence A cannot be an end node

To prove that nodes with degree 1 (other than the two end nodes) cannot be part of the path

- assume that there is a node B with degree 1 that is part of the path, but not an end node
- note that the path must use the one-and-only edge to enter B
- note that there is no edge remaining to exit B
- hence B cannot be part of the path

However, I would express the algorithm in a slightly different manner. Reading step 3b for the first time, I was confused by the need for the `else` clause that increments the length by 1. Upon further review, I finally figured out that the `else` clause is only needed at the end of the algorithm. The last pass through step 3a will leave a graph that has either one or two remaining nodes.

If two nodes remain at the end, then the graph consists of two nodes of degree 1, and one edge. The longest path through that graph has length 1. So this is a special case where removing two end nodes only removes one edge. Hence, I would rewrite the algorithm, as shown below, to make it clear that the special case only occurs at the end.

```
START
1. Make a list of nodes of the Tree storing the "Degree" of each node 
   along with a list of neighbors of the node. 

2. Initialize length=0

3. While the number of remaining nodes > 2
     a. remove all nodes having degree 1, and remove the corresponding edges  
     b. length+=2
     c. update the degree and the neighbor list of any remaining nodes 

4. if ( number of remaining nodes == 2 )
     length+=1

return length 
END
```

Comment: Thanks for the proof and the improvement.